# WPF globally styling a TextBlock inside a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I am encountering a very weird issue. I am trying to apply global styling to several controls within a `DataGrid`. Most of them work exactly how I would expect them to. However, the styling for the `TextBlock` never gets applied. Styles for `ComboBox`, `TextBox`, `Label`, and several others all are getting applied to their respective controls, but not the `TextBlock`. I have simplified the code as much as possible and the issue is still present. I have provided the code sample below.

I need the style to be applied to the `TextBlock` and I don't want to have to apply it manually to the `TextBlock`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="ANY_TEXTBLOCK_PROPERTY" Value="VALUE" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Globably Applied" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**More Information:**

- Global styles for any control other than `TextBlock` (`TextBox`, `ComboBox`, etc.) work properly.
- Defining the global style inside the `DataTemplate` will work properly.
- Directly assigning the style to the `TextBlock` using an `x:Key` will work.
- Global styles for `DataGridCell` using `TextElement.PROPERTY` will get applied to a `TextBlock`.

While some of these will get the style applied to the `TextBlock`, they have there own issues. Directly assigning the style or defining the style somewhere within a `DataGridColumn` will mean that I will have to apply the style more than once. Using the `TextElement.PROPERTY` on the `DataGridCell` will apply the style to more than just `TextBlock` controls and will limit the number of properties that you can set.

Comment: Just to understand what's going on...if you move the Style inside the TextBlock, what happens? <TextBlock.Style> <Style TargetType="TextBlock"> <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" /> </Style> </TextBlock.Style>

Comment: does the style work on a regular textblock not in the CellTemplate ?

Comment: The style is applied if it is defined within the `DataTemplate`.
The style is applied if it is directly applied to the `TextBlock`.
The style is applied if the `TextBlock` is not inside the `DataGrid`.

Comment: Interesting, could it be a style applied to datagrid that indirectly changes styles of TextBlock? Is there a style applied to Datagrid?

Comment: When you use a WPF application examining tool (like Snoop in my case), there is no style applied to the `TextBlock`.

Comment: Cédric, I thought the same thing (A style from datagrid overriding the TexkBlock style) ... but I created a new/clean WPF project in VS and tried this out and apparently trying to set the style like Bryan is doing in his question just doesn't work that way in WPF. You either have to define the style in the DataTemplate.Resources or create a TextBlock style with a x:Key and assign it to the TextBlock in the template using the resource key. It's unfortunate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So with a bit more digging and a little luck, I discovered that WPF does not apply implicit styles inside templates unless the `TargetType` derives from `Control`. Since `TextBlock` doesn't derive from `Control`, its style is not applied. So you either have to manually apply the style to every non-`Control` or define the implicit style inside the template.

The following MSDN blog post explains it in pretty good detail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wpfsdk/implicit-styles-templates-controls-and-frameworkelements

Comment: I know it's been 3 years, but maybe you still recall this issue. Before I post my own question, I thought I'd ask you first, since this is a very specific issue and from the looks of it, you have a better grasp on this. I have same/similar problem. I want to apply a style globally to all textblocks in datagrid cells, where this style would set/bind the tooltip property of each textblock to its own text. What solution/workaround did you end up using?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, like BrianP said, WPF does not work that way. But, it is possible to set the TextElement properties of the cell style as follows:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="not globably applied" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I am trying to apply stylings to controls within the `DataGrid` globally, your solution still requires me to apply the syle more than once if there is more than one column with a `TextBlock`

Comment: I have already mentioned this in my question. The problem with your solution is that it will be applied to more than just `TextBlock` controls. However, it is the only workaround that I can find to globally apply styles to `TextBlock` controls in a `DataGrid`. +1

Comment: Also, this solution will give you a limited set of properties that you can set on the `TextBlock` vs. actually using a style with a `TargetType` of `TextBlock`.